# How can I make an object of social media ids from JSON that coming as it is

Tags: flutter

```
{
  'instagram': 'aaabb',
  'facebook': 'cheche',
  'id': 'abc12',
  'address': 'asdfadf 123'
}
```

this is the json coming in on Flutter

```
{
  'id': 'abc12',
  'address': 'asdfadf 123'
  'social': {
       'instagram': 'aaabb',
       'facebook': 'cheche'
  }
}
```

Is it possible to make it like this on Flutter using json_serializable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is, that the JSON you provided isn't valid.
Theres a comma missing between 'asdfadf 123' and 'social'.
Also JSON requires double quotes (") not single QUotes (').

If you fix that you can use this code to access all properties:

```
void parseJson(String rawJson) {
var json = jsonDecode(rawJson);
print(json['id']);
print(json['address']);
print(json['social']['instagram']);
print(json['social']['facebook']);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).